# PHP : Initialized vs static registry class in performance

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, registry

is there a big difference between initializing registry class and using static methods  in performance ?

for example

```
class Registry
{
 private static $data;

 public static function set($key,$value)
 {
   self::$data[$key] = $value;
 }

 public static function get($key)
 {
   return isset(self::$data[$key]) ? self::$data[$key] : false;
 }
}
```

on the other hand

```
class Registry
{
  private $data = array();

  public function set($key,$value)
  {
    $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }

  public function get($key)
  {
    return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : false;
  }

}
```

Comment: In this context there would be a negligible performance increase on either side. A micro-optimization not worth wasting time on

Comment: so what would you suggest to use ? and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a big difference [...] in performance

No. The main concern would be the imminent violations of [Dependency Inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) with the first approach. The second approach would allow injection of the registry object, improving testability and extensibility.

Comment: so what would be the best to use ?

Comment: Either will provide the needed functionality. If you're concerned with Dependency Inversion then you should go with the second approach. If not, then the first will be simpler to implement (at the cost of testability and extensibility as I mentioned).